# wso2 session timeout with multiple products on same server

Tags: session, timeout, wso2, esb, wso2-bam

I have followed the below article and installed 3 products on same server i.e AS, ESB, BAM

[Monitoring a Web Service via ESB, Analyzing and Visualizing Results using Business Activity Monitor](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/07/monitoring-a-web-service-via-esb-analyzing-and-visualizing-results-using-bam/)

Now the problem occurred when I tried to access ESB and BAM from same browser it is continuously redirecting me to login page, seems session timeout problem or may be same cookies creating that issue.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you use localhost or same host name for all the products, given time you can access only one UI. So you can assign different host names for each product by modifying the hosts file.

Comment: just change the server host names